# When do we add certain "words" for clarity in our sentences

Tags: grammar

Not sure if these are considered modifiers, but how do we know which one is right? It seems like sometimes you need additional words to make the sentence clearer, like comparing the actual experiment results to each other, not comparing the results to the "word" experiment. Other times it's just a clarity issue.

examples.

US Supreme Court justices, (1.) those who  (2.) who  eventually held that certain forms of surveillance violated the fourth amendment.

A 2014 study found that benefits of environmental initiatives were actually higher for small business (1.) than for (2.) than Fortune 500 companies.

Researches found the observable sign-up strategy was three times more effective (1.) than 2.(than that of) the anonymous one.

Comment: Clarity is no small priority. But "than **for** Fortune 500 companies" needs the *than for* to work.

Comment: that's what I don't understand, why do we need the for. Is there a grammatical rule for that?

Comment: Without **than for**, the sentence leaves the reader with "environmental initiatives were actually higher for small business **than Fortune 500 companies** were for small business."

Comment: You mean we need to add the last part "were for small business" to make the sentence work without the for?

Comment: No. Without the proper comparison for good parallelism, the reader could misread your intention. Show us that there are two objects of the initiatives. Say that they were higher **for A** than **for B**.

Comment: So for the researcher example I posed i'm assuming for that one you would not need the that of as you are not comparing anything specific of the sign up strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, first sentence.

Although a more concise version ("US Supreme Court justices eventually held that certain forms of surveillance violated the fourth amendment.") would be a rather strong contender in terms of conveying meaning effectively (since it ties the subject, the justices, to the actions that they took more closely), an alternate version of the two choice provided in the post above would be:

"US Supreme Court justices *were* those who eventually held that certain forms of surveillance violated the fourth amendment."

*were* specifying that the following word (*those*) refers to the justices;
*those* referring to the justices;
and *who* being the link between the justices and the actions they took.

The situation, of course, would be different if the sentence instead had something following it - for example, "US Supreme Court justices, those who eventually held that certain forms of surveillance violated the fourth amendment, **would go on to...** (omitted)"

This is because the main action of the sentence is now not that the justices held that certain forms of surveillance violated the fourth amendment, but that they would **go on to...**

Otherwise the sentence is rather incomplete, without the *were*.

---

Second sentence is a completely different story.

"A 2014 study found that benefits of environmental initiatives were actually higher for small business *than for* Fortune 500 companies." would be the more correct alternative for that sentence's structure, as I'm sure others have pointed out in the comments to the question. Particularly Yosef Baskin explained it in a clear, concise way, so I'm sorry if I do seem to be a bit lazy in omitting the explanation for the second sentence.

---

Final sentence.

"Researches found the observable sign-up strategy was three times more effective *than* the anonymous one." is from my personal view the more accurate sentence grammatically, due to *than* simply comparing the two strategies without any extra moving parts and such.

However, if the sentence were "Researches found the turnout rate of the observable sign-up strategy was three times more effective _______ the anonymous one.", then the blank would be much better filled by "than that of";

*than* comparing some attribute of the observable sign-up strategy with the anonymous one;
*that of* being a phrase that implies the attribute of the anonymous sign-up strategy being compared is as written above, aka "the turnout rate".

---

In conclusion, oftentimes it's just about looking for a phrase that fulfills all of the sentence's grammatical requirement, while avoiding unnecessary drag-on.

Sorry this is such a long read.

TL;DR "were those who", "than for", "than"

P.S. All of the above is just my personal opinion; English is an ever-evolving discipline, and any and all corrections or opinions are welcome.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. In regards to the first question, just stating "those who" should be applicable right? You wouldn't need the were